# Finiteness of the Brauer group and torsion-freeness of Picard group of a rationally connected variety over an algebraically closed field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Let $X$ be a rationally connected variety over an algebraically closed field $k$. Then (1) is the Brauer group $\text{Br}(X)$ finite?
(2) is the Picard group $\text{Pic}(X)$ torsion-free?

Comment: Partial results can be found in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.05735.pdf . For instance, if X is separably rationally connected, then Pic(X) is torsion-free.  Also, if X is rationally chain connected, then there is an integer $m>0$ such that Br(X) is killed by $m$.

Comment: Also have a look at Remark 4.3 in that paper.